# after wrap into anonymous function JavaScript code not working

Tags: javascript

i have this code..which wrap in anonymous function

```
(function() {
  console.log("writting dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

window.onMessage1 = function(messageEvent) {
  console.log("writting dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
  console.log(messageEvent.data["color"]);
  return $("form#credit-info-form").append(messageEvent.data["color"]);
 };

}).call(this);
```

Error is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'

but when i'm executing above code without anonymous function wrap then it working ..

same error was on function name too i solved that with make 'onMessage1' to 'window.onMessage1' global scope..

any solution how to do with anoymous function ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you triggering/using `onMessage1 `?

Comment: after defined onMessage1 to global scope it can access simple by just 'onMessage1()'

Answer (score 0):

The `messageEvent` parameter is `undefined`, which means you're not passing an argument to `window.onMessage1` when you call it.

```
// this is the parameter---------v
window.onMessage1 = function(messageEvent) {
  console.log("writting data");

// you use it here--v
  console.log(messageEvent.data["color"]);

  //---------------------------and here--------v
  return $("form#credit-info-form").append(messageEvent.data["color"]);
};
```

---

so when you invoke it, you need to pass an argument that has a `data` property.

```
window.onMessage1(my_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
(function() {
    console.log("writting dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    window.onMessage1 = (function(messageEvent) {
        console.log("writting dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        console.log(messageEvent.data["color"]);
        //return $("form#credit-info-form").append(messageEvent.data["color"]);
    });
})();
```

Call the function

```
onMessage1({'data':{'color':'red'}});
```

But `$("form#credit-info-form")` seems that a form with `id=credit-info-form` and you are appending `messageEvent.data["color"]`, is that what you are doing ? Seems wrong to me.

Also, why you are using the anonymous function ? Since you are making the function global using `window.onMessage1 = function(){...}`.